# Combine SPARSE disks for VMWare

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation, virtual-disk

I am trying to migrate my VMWare machine to Oracle VM Box. However, looks like VM Box does not understand multiple sparse files for my VMWare machine.

I think to combine all vmdk's into single one, but cannot see any option inside VMWare. Is there any tools? (I've found something vmkfstools but under MacOS only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware Converter will allow you to combine the disk and change formats between VMware products as well as 3rd party images.